# Python- printing n'th level sublist

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a complicated list arrangement. There are many lists, and some of them have sub-lists. Now, some of the elements from the aforementioned lists are to be printed. What makes it more complicated is, the index of the value to be printed is in an excel file, as shown here:

```
   [list_1,1,2] #Means - list[1][2] is to be printed (sub-lists are there)
   [list_2,7]   #Means - list_2[7] is to be printed (no sub-list)
   ................
   [list_100,3,6] #Means list_100[3][6] is to be printed (sub list is there)
```

The number of the lists is so long, so that I was using a for loop and multiple *if statements*. For example (pseudo code):

```
for i in range(100): #because 100 lists are there in excel
    if len(row_i) == 3:
        print(list_name[excel_column_1_value][excel_column_2_value])
    else:
        print(list_name[excel_column_1_value])
```

Please note that, the excel sheet is only to get the list name and index, the lists are all saved in the main code.

Is there any way to avoid the `if statements` and automate that part as well ? Asking because, the if condition value is only based on the length given by the excel sheet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry i don't get you question could you provide a more clear example?

Comment: Show us a sample list in python.

Comment: @Pils19, thanks for commenting. Edited, am I clear now ?

Comment: Please update your question with the approaches you have tried and what problems you faced.

Comment: @PauloScardine, thanks for commenting, please have a look at my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have data like this:

```
data = {
    "list1": [[100, 101, 102], [110, 111, 112], [120, 121, 123]],
    "list2": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    "list3": [[200, 201, 202], [210, 211, 212], [220, 221, 223]],
}
```

If it is homework, your teacher probably want you to solve it using recursion, but I recommend using an iterative version in Python unless you can assure you would not stack more than 999 calls:

```
fetch_element(data, listname, *indices):
    value = data[listname]
    for index in indices:
        value = value[index]
    return value
```

Then you have the list of elements you want:

```
desired = [
    ["list1", 0, 0],
    ["list2", 7],
    ["list3", 2, 2],
]
```

Now you can do:

```
>>> [fetch_element(data, *line) for line in desired]
[100, 7, 223]
```

Which is the same as:

```
>>> [data["list1"][0][0], data["list2"][7], data["list3"][2][2]]
[100, 7, 223]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Paulo, this was the answer I was seeking for.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a better example? how does your list look like and what's the desired output when printing?

You can open the file, read the indexes and lists names you want to print into a list and iterate that list to print what you want.

There are many ways to print a list a simple one, you can use:

```
mylist = ['hello', 'world', ':)']
print ', '.join(mylist)


mylist2 = [['hello', 'world'], ['Good', 'morning']]
for l in mylist2:
   print(*l)
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Alg. I have edited my answer. What I am asking is how to automate the printing when I have a situation like: print: list[a][b] or list[a]. I mean how to automatically put the number of indexes required.